# what type decay in the hard wood floor joist

Tags: timber-framing

Today I noticed a 10cm long softened line along the hard wood floor joist and used a scraper to clear it, and all powder came down leaving a 1cm deep strip. I further noticed a few other spots like that. There is this large one with a hole running along the joist deep inside - used a screw driver to test.

What is it wondering dry spot? How can it be fixed? Should I be concerned?

[image]

Comment: Brown rot is a common fungus that  your mind wouldn't immediately map to "fungus." The carpenter ants led me to mine. Are there conditions in the neighborhood of this damage that could encourage mold growth? Is this a crawlspace without vapor barrier, for instance?

Comment: I just sprayed a bunch of lumber exposed to the elements with a cheap borate based solution the other day as a prophylactic fungicide. Pressure treated wood uses copper compounds as its fungicide. My borate stuff was odorless, but the copper compounds stink, stink, stink in my experience.